# PickerView ViewForRow Doesn't Recognize Components

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

I'm using multiple components to make a timer. My pickerView doesn't recognize my second dataSource when I incorporate it with ViewForRow

```
let hourDataSource = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let minDataSource = ["0", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel()

    if component == 0 {
        label.text = String(row)
        label.textAlignment = .center
    } else if component == 1 {
        label.text = String(row)
        label.textAlignment = .center
    }
    print(component)
    return label

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if let label = pickerView.view(forRow: row, forComponent: component) as? UILabel {

        if component == 0, row > 1 {
            label.text = String(row) + " hours"
        } else if component == 0 {
            label.text = String(row) + " hour"
        } else if component == 1 {
            label.text = String(row) + " min"
        }
    }

    //print(component)
    let hour = dataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    let min = minDataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
    timerPickerViewLbl.text = "\(hour):\(min) hrs"
}
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if component == 0 {
        return dataSource[row]
    } else {
        return minDataSource[row]
    }
}
```

I'm printing the components so I know its getting called. When I delete the viewForRow function, my data is correct for the 1st column and 2nd column. But I lose the hour and minute label next to my data. But adding it makes my 2nd column return the same data as my 1st. What's am I missing?

Comment: What is the purpose of `viewForRow` and `titleForRow` ? What do you actually want on your screen?

Comment: I implemented titleForRow to get the data to appear within the separate components (columns). I actually don't know why I use viewForRow, but as I was researching, I found out I needed it to add the label "hour" and "min" inside my  separate column as I'm switching times. Currently, viewForRow gives me that affect as I'm switching time. But the data for the 2nd column is wrong.

Comment: Yes you are only supposed to use one of the two delegates. Not both of them together.

Comment: so for titleForRow, I can easily write the syntax above to give me my data. I just don't know how to do it within viewForRow. It gives me errors.

Comment: Check my answer. Remove the `viewForRow` from your code. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need. You are only supposed to use one of the delegates, either `titleForRow` or `viewForRow` because both of them do the same thing, i.e, give title to the row. Your problem is in the `didSelect` delegate where you are actually returning the data.

```
let hourDataSource = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let minDataSource = ["0", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let hour = dataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    let min = minDataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
    timerPickerViewLbl.text = "\(hour):\(min) hrs"
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0, row > 1 {
        return "\(hourDataSource[row]) hours"
    } else if component == 0 {
        return "\(hourDataSource[row]) hour"
    } else if component == 1 {
        return "\(minDataSource[row]) mins"
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: But I'm still not getting the "hour" or "min" next to my numbers in the pickerView. I'm trying to make it look similar to Apple's timer in the Clock App.

Comment: @KennyHo Oh i see what you need now. Check the updated answer. Alternatively, you can have the dataSource itself like how you need it to be.

Comment: When I use your code I get an error "Use of unresolved indentifier 'label'". Then when I added "let label = UILabel()". I get "Missing return in a function expected to return 'String?'". Thank you so much for your help btw. I really appreciate it <3

Comment: @KennyHo I changed the answer, it was an oversight while changing the code.

Comment: Its still giving me an error "Missing return in a function expected to return String?"

Comment: @KennyHo How about now? Are your variables all exactly like in my answer or did you change the array to [Int]? Anyhow it should work now.

Comment: Everything is like yours but I'm still getting the same error message of missing return 'String?'

Comment: @KennyHo I missed a line at the end of the `titleForRow`. Check now. Should work fine.

Comment: the problem seems to come from "else if".

Comment: Ohhh! Perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: That method always need to return something. So from the code the compiler thinks that since there is only an `if` and two `else if`'s. If they fail there is nothing returning.